# Extending a measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,S)$ a measurable space and $D\in S\setminus\{\emptyset\}$. Let $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ a Borel-measurable function, where $D$ has the $\sigma$-algebra $S_D:=\{A\cap D:A\in S\}$.

I proved that there exists $h:X\to\mathbb{R}$ measurable such that $h\restriction_{D}=f$. In fact, it is easy to see that if $h$ is defined by $h(x)=f(x)$ if $x\in D$ and $h(x)=0$ elsewhere, then $h$ works well. In this proof, I used that $S_D\subseteq S$, and that is because $D\in S$.

My question is, is this false if $D\notin S$? What do you think?

Thanks.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are asking the following question:

Let $D \subset X$, not necessarily measurable. Suppose $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is *any* function. Does $f$ extend to a measurable function $h$ defined on the whole of $X$?

Comment: No @Frank , $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ must be also measurable